# I want to create a variable that can send int, float and double values to my custom ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have my custom arraylist MyArrayList. That can only store int, float or double values. But i want to get that from user input. I have a temp String variable that gets input as string. Now I want to add that 
arraylist. so the string has to be converted to its type first.

```
class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if(e instanceof Integer || e instanceof Float || e instanceof Double) {
            super.add(e);
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException("Please enter Integer, Float or Double");
        }
    }
}

public class TestArrayList{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        MyArrayList<Object> arraylist = new MyArrayList<>();
        Object object = new Object();
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter Elements");
            System.out.println("To stop input press '.'");
            String temp;
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                temp = scanner.nextLine();
                try {                   
                    object = temp;
                } catch(Exception e) {}
                if(temp.equals(".")) break;
                else
                    arraylist.add(temp);
            }
            scanner.close();
            System.out.println(arraylist.toString());       
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Variables can't send anything anywhere. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit odd requirement because you can only store `Object` in your class and you have to use `instanceof` when you get elements from a list. To convert the string a simple way is to try to convert and then catch but ignore any exception like this

```
public static Object convertToSomeNumber(String input) {
    try {
        return Integer.valueOf(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {
        return Double.valueOf(input);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now you can use it on your `temp` variable and add the result to the list if it is not null.

Note that I ignored Float so you need to add that yourself if you want to support it.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was thinking, but I wanted to know, whether java has some in-built feature for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and I would also suggest to change your arrayList to use Number instead of Object. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

You now also could have Byte/Short and some other types in this array list (but you might even want this), but in general you won't need you your own implementation of the ArrayList.

Answer (score -1):

List just only one type;  if you want use more type in to list; use Object;

and it's not recommended;

any way, mabe have more ways to implements business;